# Unityのコンソールエラーの対処が解からない

Tags: c#, unity3d

コンソールエラーで5行目に `;` や `{}` が不足してると書かれてると思うのですが、public classには必要ないはず。
どこに `{}` をつけるのですか。

また、"Top level statement must precede namespace and type declarations." と書かれていますがどういう意味ですか。

**コンソールのエラー画面:**
[image]

#### 試したこと

`MonoBehaviour` の後に `;` を付けたらエラーが消えたので、`{}` も5行目のいろんなところに試したけどエラーがついたまま。

コード

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Car controll: MonoBehaviour
{
    float Speed = 0;
    float LimitSpeed = 70f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update


    // Update is called once per frame
    void FIxedUpdate()
    {
        Rigidbody rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Vector3 force = new Vector3(10f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Force);

        if (rb.velocity.magnitude > LimitSpeed)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x / 1.1f, rb.velocity.y, rb.velocity.z / 1.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

クラス名に余計な空白が含まれています。

```
public class Car controll
                ^
```